# retrieve average value of a field in mongoDb between documents selected in range date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

i'm tryng to calculate the avg of a field in mongo db using node.js. From the UI i select the startDate of the range and the endDate and also the field that i want to get the avg. The result of the query is always an empty array, but  i'm sure that there are values in the db.

this is the backend code which calculate avg of a field (parametro). the two date passed from UI are fetched by a datepicker.
app.post('/getMedia', async (req,res) => {
console.log(req.body)

```
const firstDate = req.body.firstDate
const secondDate = req.body.secondDate

try {
  await client.connect()
  const database = client.db('xyz');
  const collection = database.collection(req.body.collection)

  const result = await collection.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        timestamp: {
          $gte: firstDate,
          $lte: secondDate
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        averageField: { $avg: req.body.parametro }
      }
    }
  ]).toArray();
  const average = result[0].averageField;
  console.log(average)
  res.json(average)
} catch (error) {
  res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred' });
  console.log(error)
}
```

})

the document in mongo db is saved like this:
_id
6499a3819d2621297e1b4f03
fc
"99"
spO2
"98"
systolic
"140"
diastolic
"90"
timestamp
2023-06-26T14:01:48.530+00:00

Comment: Have you tried to remove "$match" and "$group" to see that result come? Because reason can be in: 1) DB connection; 2) $match; 3) $group.

Answer (score 0):

Below are few assumptions :-

1. req.body.parametro, contains the name of the key for which you are trying to find the average value.
2. req.body.parametro does not starts with $.
3. req.body.firstDate and req.body.secondDate is a js date object. Though if it is a string also then there won't be much concerns, mongo will apply string comparison rules.

Solution :-
You need to add $ prefix in front of req.body.parametro value, else mongo will treat it as normal string. your code should look like.

```
{ $avg: `\$${req.body.parametro}` }
```